# How can I be able to `mv` a directory owned by root?

Tags: directory, mv, privileges

System: Linux Mint 19.

Situation: I do not understand the following.

How can I be able to `mv` a directory owned by `root`?

Some information, that might be useful:

Actual working directory:

```
$ pwd

/home/vlastimil/mail
```

The directory I claim I am able to rename without using `sudo` is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K Oct 24 14:34 test1/
```

The command I accidentally run without `sudo`:

```
$ mv test test1
```

And voila, I stand surprised by the fact it went ok. Why is that?

And it is reproducible. I can do e.g.:

```
$ mv test1 test2
```

Just to make it crystal clear, I run that as a normal user:

```
$ id -un

vlastimil
```

I do not suppose it would be a bug. Instead, it has probably something to do with the fact, that the directory is placed within my `$HOME`, am I on the right track?

Comment: The directory above it belongs to the user, and the user as write privileges on it... no news there. You are on the right track.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63284/117549